# intuition for using multinomial coefficient formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My textbook doesn't do a good explanation in explaining multinomial coefficients. What type of problem would we use multinomial coefficient formula?

Is it like the example below that given different types, we are to find permutations of those? In brief, is it a special case of permutation in which different types are concerned?

> **Example**
>
> Among nine orchids for a line of orchids along one wall, three are white, four lavendar and two yellow. The number of different colour displays is then $${9 \choose 3,4,2}=\frac{9!}{3!4!2!}=1260$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explanation for this case (can be extended to the complete case): 9 flowers in all, 3 of them white and $9 - 3 =6$ nowhite. Thus, there are $\binom{9}{3}$ way to arrange this. But you also have to arrange the 6 nonwhites, 4 lavender and 2 yellow, in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways. In all:

$\begin{equation*}
\binom{9}{3} \cdot \binom{6}{2}
  = \frac{9!}{3! 6!}
         \cdot \frac{6!}{2! 4!}
  = \frac{9!}{3! 2! 4!}
  = \binom{9}{3, 2, 4}
\end{equation*}$

Answer (score 1):

The multinomial coefficient describes the number of permutations of a group of objects, some of which may be identical. If the distinct types of objects number $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ and there are $N$ objects in total, the coefficient $\binom N{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n}$ gives the number of distinct permutations of them.

Comment: Where $x_1x_2y$ and $x_2x_1y$ are counted as one thing, right? (using subscripts to distinguish identical elements...)

Comment: @PrudiiArca Yes.